# Different ways to establish constants

Tags: java

In java, is there an accepted preferred method for doing seething like the following

```
public class SomeSubclass extends SomeSuperclass {

    private static int x = 3;

    public SomeSubclass() {
        super(x);
    }
}
```

As in, if I have many subclasses that extends from one super class and they differ by some constant, what is the best way to implement this? Here you can imagine each subclass just changing the value of x and any other constants.

Is it good practice to have a lot of instance variables and pass keep the constructirs uniform? Also, when I realize that my variables are not actually constant. Would it be better to set them to public static final?

Also, regarding constructors:

```
public class Someclass extends Aclass {
    public Someclass() {
        super(3);
        setY(9);
    }
}
```

Assume that every subclass that extends the superclass makes a one argument call to the constructor and also a call to setY, a setter method in the super class. Is it better to have setter method calls in the constructor or to have constructors in the superclass that will alaccept and automatically perform the function of setY

Comment: I guess a more concrete example would be better.

Comment: The example isn't helping in understanding your problem. Voting as unclear.

Comment: As @NarendraPathai said, you've simplified the problem way too much, such that there's no real way to know what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the main reasons we do object-oriented programming - objects are polymorphic. If many objects differ in some property or behaviour, make it as a virtual getter/setter or method:

```
class SomeSubclass extends SomeSuperclass {
    @Override
    int getX() { return 3; }

    public SomeSubclass() {
        super();
    }
}

abstract class SomeSuperclass {
    abstract int getX();
    SomeSuperclass() {
        System.out.println( this.getX() );        
    }
}
```

Here it will work because in Java all method calls (even from a constructor, sic!) are virtual.

In general avoid calling overridable methods from constructor (this can cause memory and reference violations if we call something that assumes whole object was already constructed).

In your case, please consider: is inheritance really the best mechanism you need here? Maybe encapsulation, state, or something like that would be better, more natural solution.

I mean, if you really need some property of subclass in superclass' constructor, please consider making `SomeSuperclass` a *member* of `SomeSubclass` instead of inheriting from it.

If it is some bigger thing: please consider making third object - a state - with all the members and getters, which will be stored in every instance of the class.

In simple scenario just make `static final int` and pass to super constructor as argument.